# Permission denied when executing Symfony Demo app through Docker

Tags: symfony, docker

In my first attempt at running a more complex application through Docker, I selected the [Symfony Demo](https://github.com/symfony/demo) app and assembled a docker build structure to accommodate it.

- The first image is httpd: it runs as root (dropping to www-data afterwards) and talks through the 'server' custom network.
- The second image is php (fpm): it runs as root (dropping to www-data afterwards) and also talks through the 'server' custom network.
- The third image is composer: it runs as UID and GID 1000. Its entrypoint command is `composer create-project symfony/symfony-demo symfony-demo`
- All containers share the same bind mount, where the symfony-demo app is located.

Then I go to localhost:8080 in the browser just to end up with a Symfony error:

```
The stream or file "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/symfony-demo/var/log/dev.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

The thing is... this file mentioned doesn't even exist at /var/log/. That folder is empty.

All files in the bind mount have permissions 1000:1000 (my user UID/GID) and are configured like this: `-rw-r--r--`.

I've tried running httpd and php as: UID 33 (www-data) and GID 33; UID 0 (root) and GID 33 (and vice-versa); and also as 1000:1000 or 1000:33, but all these combinations (when they successfully get httpd/php to start up) result in the same error.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  httpd:
    build: "./httpd/"
    container_name: "webserver"
    depends_on:
      - php
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - server
    volumes:
      - ../app:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
  php:
    build: "./php/"
    depends_on:
      - composer
    container_name: "php"
    networks:
      - server
    volumes:
      - ../app:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
  composer:
    build: "./composer/"
    container_name: "composer"
    user: "1000:1000"
    volumes:
      - ../app:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
networks:
  server:
    driver: bridge
```

composer Dockerfile:

```
FROM composer:1.8

WORKDIR /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/

CMD ["composer", "create-project", "symfony/symfony-demo", "symfony-demo"]
```

httpd Dockerfile:

```
FROM httpd:2.4

COPY ./config/httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
COPY ./config/httpd-vhosts.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
COPY ./config/php-fpm.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/php-fpm.conf

WORKDIR /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
```

php Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

RUN cp "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
COPY ./config/timezone.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/
COPY ./config/www.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y libicu-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install intl

WORKDIR /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On second thoughts:** my previous solution (as is) doesn't work in RHEL/Fedora/CentOS, because www-data does not exist there by default, causing Docker to fail to start.

---

#### My new solution - distro agnostic

For simplicity, I've decided to simply write composer's entrypoint script to set -rw-rw---- permissions at /app. That way, I can run composer as user 1000 and the same group PHP runs as (a new user and group was created just for that). Now PHP can write to SQLite3 database files inside the project and composer writes as user 1000, which I can edit.

It's basically what @habibun said, but I only need to give group write permissions, not full write permissions.

*Be aware that SELinux will deny composer write access to your bind mount. You must configure SELinux to allow this operation.*

> This is my repository where this project is stored, if you're looking for a reference: https://github.com/o-alquimista/symfony-demo-docker/

---

#### User namespace solution - works fine for Debian/Ubuntu hosts

Composer should write to /app as user 33 (www-data), and so should php and httpd after they drop privileges. I was able to keep present permission settings (only owner can write) by making use of [user namespaces](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/). The user www-data is now mapped to the range 967 and beyond, which will result in user 33 being = me (user 1000).

Now all containers can write where they need to, and I can edit the project files as an unprivileged user.

Answer (score 0):

just give the write permission

```
chmod -R 777 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/symfony-demo/var/log/dev.log
```

here symfony doc for file permission: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html

Comment: If I run Symfony Demo outside Docker, I do not need to fix any permissions. It just works. Why is this not the case when I run it within Docker? That's what I want to understand and solve the right way, by causing the file to be created with the right permissions already.